# dagger 2 viewmodels and ViewModelProvider.Factory

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

Recently I had problems with a **ViewModelProvider.Factory** due to it was not loading all ViewModels of the project.

I have Activities and fragments. The activity ones are loaded without any problem, however  I've tried to encapsulate FragmentViewModels inside the module where I'm creating the Fragment.

a bit of code:

```
@Module(includes = [
  ... ,... ,...
])
class UIModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideViewModelFactory(viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>)
        : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

        return object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return requireNotNull(viewModels[modelClass]).get() as T
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Activity Builder

```
@Module
abstract class MainActivityBuilder {
....

@ActivityScope
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules [XXXFragmentModule::class])
abstract fun bindBottomNavigationActivity(): BottomNavigationActivity
```

}

so this is the XXXFragmentModule

```
@Module(includes = [ActividadesFragmentModule.ViewModule::class])
abstract class ActividadesFragmentModule {

  ....

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun contributeSuggestedFragment(): SuggestedFragment


    @Module
    abstract class ViewModule {

        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @ViewModelKey(SuggestedViewModel::class)
        internal abstract fun bindSuggestedViewModel(viewModel: SuggestedViewModel): ViewModel
    }
}
```

this does not work, the **viewModels** of the first block of code does only have the ViewModels of the activities, it does not add this last ViewModel. 
However if the  **@Module(includes = [ActividadesFragmentModule.ViewModule::class])** is done in **ActivityBuilder** it does work perfeclty

```
@Module(includes = [ActividadesFragmentModule.ViewModule::class])
abstract class MainActivityBuilder
```

does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to remove the scope from your `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

Comment: it does work  however, what does it mean? I'll create a new ViewModelProvider.Factory each time?  Normally I've always used it as Singleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the scope from your `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

`@Singleton` will never ever get anything from your Activity or Fragment scope. By removing the scope you create a new factory within every component—where it can collect the additional bindings that you added in those lower scopes.

The factory itself is pretty lightweight so there should be no issues if it remains unscoped and gets recreated. `@Reusable` "scope" should work as well.

Comment: I've done this and it works. I've also added a break point each time this provider is called and it increments the number of elements, so it starts with two viewmodels, then three, then four...  what does this mean? it will reuse the viewmodels ?

Comment: @JoseMLechon `@Reuseable` is scope-like, with no guarantee of uniqueness. It caches the object to be reused, rather than recreated every time.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i was a bit confused with this.